# Can copper pour be used as an alternative to large traces?

Tags: pcb-design

This is a general question, but if I am designing a PCB that needs a trace width of 110 mil, would I be able to use the copper pour instead of drawing out the large trace? The reason I am asking is for PCB's that have a lot of components that don't allow for large trace widths. Thanks.

Comment: Consider this: if someone reworks your PCB later on, they may get a layout in which your copper pour will have a narrow bottleneck somewhere, and won't realize it's a problem until actual samples are produced which fail tests.

Comment: Adding to @Dmitry's comment -- some (many) PCB houses run the gerbers you send them through some kind of processing (reshaping of traces and pours) to simplify manufacturability. In my experience. This has resulted in missing and truncated traces and pours and has caused unwanted islanding of ground regions and mismatched differential trace impedances.

Comment: Nowadays, if I want to use a ground pour as a trace (say, for the nodes of a switching power supply circuit), I put down the pour areas, and then overlay them with traces on the same layer in my PCB design tool, and tell the PCB house that they must at least respect the dimensions of the traces embedded in the pours, even if they need to hack up the pour dimensions.

Comment: @schadjo: Alternatively, at least in some tools, one can lay down traces first and then specify that pours are generally allowed to overlay traces on the same net (I don't know if one can specify an exception for portions of traces that are very close to component pads, but that might be helpful).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The reason I am asking is for PCB's that have a lot of components that don't allow for large trace widths.

Yes, you can do that.

However, I'd still recommend using a high-width trace where possible, and then just connecting the small components using short, thinner traces. That way, you can guarantee the wide trace for most of the distance, your design rule check has an easier time, and actually laying out the high-current traces means that you can do that *before* you place all the other traces – which is desirable, because especially in fast-changing high-current signals, you want to avoid large current "detours" and loops.

Answer (score 8):

The only difference between a trace and a copper pour is how they're created in your EDA -- a trace is defined explicitly, a copper pour is created implicitly from everything that's left over. Once the board is manufactured, there's no difference.

So long as the copper pour meets the required trace width, it's fine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using filled zones instead of a trace is common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Having a copper pour completely cover a trace is a common practice.  Using one instead of a trace, however, is probably not a good idea.  Ground traces should generally be given routing priority over most other traces, so good ground routing is established long before anything would know what parts of the board will be covered with a copper pour.  If one places traces between a bypass cap and the power/ground connections of the appropriate chip, one can ensure that the cap and chip will be well connected.  If one relies upon a ground pour to connect them, one may end up with the cap and chip connected via a long thick "C-shaped" copper poor that requires current from the chip to flow halfway around the board in order to reach the nearby cap.  Such a design might pass an automated design rule check, but fail to actually work reliably if manufactured.